# UTF8 character Issue in MySQL and PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpexcel

I have a MySQL database with collation latin1_swidish_ci. I am having 2 problems.

1. Weird characters like triangles are showing up in my webpage when I echo it.
2. When I export the data to Excel File using PHPEXCEL, The characters like é are not being populated in the cell. All the characters after é are being deleted from the string !

Export Script:

```
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

**The problems are happening only in the server ! Its working perfectly fine in my Localhost. Please suggest.**

Comment: You need to ensure that all string values stored in cells are UTF-8 strings; if your database is storing values in other charsets, then you'll need to use [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) functions to convert them to UTF-8 first

Answer (score 0):

How are your pages encoded? If your HTML is encoded UTF8 while your database is using latin1_swedish_ci you're going to have this happen from time to time.

Comment: You could try using `utf8_decode` on your input before sending it to your DB http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php There's also `iconv` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: The problem is that I dont have control over the DB data. Its already there.

Comment: You could try `utf8_decode` and see if that fixes the output. It's been a while since I had to mess with latin1 so I'm not sure (off the top of my head) if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using UTF8 encoding in database connection and meta tags. Where as in the database collation it is latin1_swidish_ci

So I just removed the UTF8 declarations and Its working Fine. Thanks everyone.